# Pull out array of objects and use their fields out of the array (MongoDB aggregation framework)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I don't know if this is possible to do, but suppose I have documents like these:

```
[
  {
    "L": [
      {
        "L1": 1
      }, 
      {
        "L6": 2
      }, 
      {
        "L2": 1
      }
    ], 
    "week": 26, 
    "weekEnd": "2020-06-28", 
    "weekStart": "2020-06-22"
  },
  {
    "L": [
      {
        "L5": 1
      }, 
      {
        "L2": 1
      }, 
      {
        "L3": 1
      }
    ], 
    "week": 19, 
    "weekEnd": "2020-05-10", 
    "weekStart": "2020-05-04"
  }, 
]
```

As you all can see, the array `L`can have different objects with fields like `L1, L2, L3, ..., L30`.
I would like to pull out the fields of each object out of the `L` array.
Expected result:

```
[
  {
    "L1": 1,
    "L6": 2,
    "L2": 1, 
    "week": 26, 
    "weekEnd": "2020-06-28", 
    "weekStart": "2020-06-22"
  },
  {
    "L5": 1,
    "L2": 1,
    "L3": 1, 
    "week": 19, 
    "weekEnd": "2020-05-10", 
    "weekStart": "2020-05-04"
  }
]
```

I could do this "from scratch", but I would have to write every field one by one in a `$project` stage. Is there a automatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) (available from v3.6) to merge all keys of objects in an array.
First you'll have to merge objects in array `L`, then you have to merge the result with the root document `$$ROOT`

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $replaceRoot: { // 3. replace the result as root document
    newRoot: {
      $mergeObjects: [ // 2. merge with root document
        {
          $mergeObjects: "$L" // 1. merge objects in array L
        },
        "$$ROOT"
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: { // remove original L array
    L: false
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_C-1BUvLwfx)

If you are using v4.2 or later you can use the following slightly shorter syntax

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $replaceWith: {
    $mergeObjects: [
      {
        $mergeObjects: "$L"
      },
      "$$ROOT"
    ]
  }
},
{
  $unset: "L"
})
```

Comment: Perfect! I used `$replaceRoot` due my early version of MongoDB and worked like a charm.